# Two variables Taylor's expansion

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I guess that Taylor's expansion about $(0,0)$ is useful for finding value of $\dfrac{\partial^{4n}}{\partial x^{2n}\partial y^{2n}} \left (\dfrac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}\right)(0,0) $. How can it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write the given function
$$f(x,y):={1\over 1+x^2+y^2}$$ as a power series in $x$ and $y$ as follows:
$$f(x,y)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty(-1)^j (x^2+y^2)^j=\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j\sum_{k+l=j}{j!\over k!l!} x^{2k}y^{2l}\ .$$ Now differentiate termwise $2n$ times with respect to $x$ and $2n$ times with respect to $y$. Since we are only interested in the final value at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ only the term with $k=l=n$, and therefore $j=2n$, gives a contribution. I obtained
$${\partial^{4n}f\over\partial x^{2n}\partial y^{2n}}(0,0)={\bigl((2n)!\bigr)^3\over\bigl(n!\bigr)^2}\ .$$